# How do I include a var inside a var using {}

Tags: javascript, variables

I have:

```
      var lineArea = new Chartist.Line('#line-area', {
      labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
~break
```

I have to replace the abcd with a var:

```
var mondays = document.getElementById('mondays').innerHTML; alert(mondays); var lineArea = new Chartist.Line('#line-area', { labels: [{mondays}], series: [ [0, 20, 10, 45, 20, 36, 21, 0], [0, 5, 22, 14, 32, 12, 28, 0] ] }, { low: 0, showArea: true, fullWidth: true, onlyInteger: true, axisY: { low: 0, scaleMinSpace: 50, }, axisX: { showGrid: false } });
```

However, this (and other things I've blindly tried) don't work.  Actually results in *[object Object]*
 being displayed.

How do I insert a var within a var like this?

Comment: open devtool and see what is `mondays`

Comment: What exactly is the value of `mondays`?

Comment: `document.getElementById('mondays').innerHTML` will be a string and `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` is an array. They aren't really interchangable so it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: "Actually results in [object Object] being displayed." — Then lots of your code is missing. Nothing in the code you've provided will cause *anything* to be displayed. You need to provide a [mcve] and a *clear problem statement*.

Comment: Provide the HTML of the `id=mondays`

Comment: Actually, mondays is 'there' and formatted correctly.

Comment: `<div id='mondays' style='display: none;'>'04/29', '05/06', '05/13', '05/20', '05/27', '06/03', '06/10', '06/17', '06/24'</div>`

Comment: If anything, you want `labels: mondays.innerHTML.split(',')`, or something along those lines.

Comment: here:
 `var mondays = document.getElementById('mondays').innerHTML;
    alert(mondays);
    var lineArea = new Chartist.Line('#line-area', {
        labels: [{mondays}],
        series: [
            [0, 20, 10, 45, 20, 36, 21, 0],
            [0, 5, 22, 14, 32, 12, 28, 0]
        ]
    }, {
            low: 0,
            showArea: true,
            fullWidth: true,
            onlyInteger: true,
            axisY: {
                low: 0,
                scaleMinSpace: 50,
            },
            axisX: {
                showGrid: false
            }
        });`

Comment: if I manually poke in what *is* monday, it works fine.

Comment: OK, so now this has been downvoted into the gutter.  Sorry, I'm not a javascript guy.  I generated the the contents of the hidden div from php, formatting it exactly as would be pasted into the js.  I then figured out how to get that innerHTML and got stuck there.  I tried double curlies, $, brackets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it on my own.
I'll bore you with my solution... *the smoothest solution*:
I put the whole thing into a PHP file, since the string was generated in PHP anyway.  Also, since the PHP variable that I was hiding in a div was already called '$mondays', all I had to do was this:
`labels: [<?php echo $mondays ?>],`
and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Note that manually formatting a string to appear like a Javascript snippet which could be copy-and-pasted into Javascript source code is *not* the way to go. `$mondays` should be *an array* containing strings, e.g. `array("04/29", ...)`, which you then format into an equivalent *Javascript array* using `json_encode`, and then directly use *as array*: `labels: <?= json_encode($mondays); ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t try and pass a string literal into an array declaration , simply generate the array by splitting a string inside of the innerHTML. This is the simplest solution, you could store encoded JSON inside the innerHTML and parse it but this seems much simpler.

```
//Assume innerHTML = "a,b,c'd"
var monday = document.getElementById('mondays').innerHTML;    

//Split the string based of comma to generate an array of strings
var mondaysArr = monday.split();

//Pass in the array
var lineArea = new Chartist.Line('#line-area', mondaysArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

1. take inner html
2. split on a comma
3. remove quotes

```js
text = document.getElementById('mondays').innerHTML
array = text.split(', ')

// !!
labels = array.map(e => e.split("'").join(""))

console.log('text', text)
console.log('array', array)

// !!
console.log('labels', labels)
```

```html
<div id='mondays' style='display: none;'>'04/29', '05/06', '05/13', '05/20', '05/27', '06/03', '06/10', '06/17', '06/24'</div>
```

Comment: sorry, this broke it.  I'm too ignorant on this.  I hate, what I'm assuming is, JSON because of these very quirks.  But, thanks for taking a shot.